# Flashplayer not working

Tags: flash-player

today I have updated my sources.list + upgraded my applications and faced a few problems, of most I got rid off, but nevertheless there is still 1 remaining issue: I use Chromium and when I visit sites which contain Flash content the browser tells me that I need Flash 10, this problem exists of sites which contain Flash-content but weirdly Youtube is not concerned. So, I thought: well, I should install flashplugin-nonfree, which was not installed before and it still does not work, Synaptic says it is properly installed but chromium shows the same errors over and over again. And on Iceweasel everything works properly, even without the flashplugin-nonfree, on the Adobe-site I got a message that I have the latest version installed. So, is Flashplayer autoinstalled for Iceweasel, since it worked also before installing the plugin? Or is it a Flash-substitute? Since the issue arised after upgrading my next step is to downgrade but since flashplugin is by default not installed I don´t really know what to downgrade. I use Crunchbang Waldorf 11. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to chrome:plugins and verify that flash is appearing and is enabled. If it doesn't appear then chromium isn't detecting it. Chromium has been planning to drop support for npapi plugins such as flash player(although the ppapi flash built into Google Chrome will continue to be supported).

Comment: okay, thanks, yeah in iceweasel flash is detected not in chromium, but what wonders me is, that everything worked before even without the flashplugin. apparently it was installed by default for iceweasel, but if flash isnt the problem, since it was not installed before, what is the problem? could it be that I have to downgrade chromium?

Comment: Maybe. For the moment I would check and see if the repo maintainers have multiple versions available(such as devel and beta). If they don't I would attempt to find a 3rd party repository or attempt to install the ppapi version of flash, which can be extracted from Google Chrome.